# Check if item is in listbox Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

```
dim foo as string = "hello"
```

check if foo is in listbox1?

```
if listbox1.items.contains(foo) then
```

does not work

Comment: You should accept Codemunkeee's answer by clicking the check mark next to his/her answer if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim foo As String
foo = "Hello"
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString = foo Then
        MsgBox(i)
    End If
Next
```

i is the index on the listbox where the item was found.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working then "hello" isn't an item in the listbox items collection.  Remember that " hello","hello ","Hello", and "hello" are all different strings.  Also .Contains will only compare whole items it won't find a substring within an individual item.  You'll need a custom sub routine if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try it out,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim found As String = ""
    Dim foo As String
    foo = "hello"

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString = foo Then
            found = (i)
        End If
    Next

    If found = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("not found your word!!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("found hello, word!")
    End If

End Sub
```